# what's root cause of "A start job is running for Create Volatile Files and Directories"

Tags: linux, boot, debian, kernel

Stuck at "A start job is running for Create Volatile Files and Directories" after reboot a server(**Debian 9.5, 64bit**), and solve by this **["boot-stuck-at-a-start-job-is-running-for-create-volatile-files-and-directories"](https://serverfault.com/questions/987488/boot-stuck-at-a-start-job-is-running-for-create-volatile-files-and-directories)**.

I can't figure out what is the **root cause** of this issue, although search from many questions which are not refer the **root cause** but just the varied solutions that not meet me.

We have not reach the limit of file or (sub) directory, and set the `dir_nlink` for `ext4`.

```
# sudo tune2fs -l /dev/debian-vg/root | grep dir_nlink
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent
 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
```

And the are more than **50%** capacity of `inode` and `disk`.

The original `/tmp` directory only little file and directory, total disk space usage only **1G**.

Comment: Reference this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1098676/whats-root-cause-of-a-start-job-is-running-for-create-volatile-files-and-direc